# Why do I need to cast this generic return value?

Tags: swift, syntax

I'm confused about generics here. The static keyword is making it difficult for me to understand.

```
import CoreData

@objc(Performer)
public class Performer: NSManagedObject, Fetchable {

  @NSManaged public var dob: Date

  @NSManaged public var firstName: String

  @NSManaged public var lastName: String
}

protocol Fetchable {
  static func fetchAll<T: NSManagedObject>(withPredicate predicate: NSPredicate?, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [T]
}

extension Fetchable {

  static func fetchAll<T: NSManagedObject>(withPredicate predicate: NSPredicate?, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [T] {
    let entityName = String(describing: self)
    let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: entityName)
    request.predicate = predicate
    return try context.fetch(request)
  }
}

let performers: [NSManagedObject] = try! Performer.fetchAll(in: context)
```

//Or

```
let performers: [Performer] = try! Performer.fetchAll(in: context) as! [Performer]
```

//Or

EDIT: This line was focus of my question as it was throwing an error. But fixed it by killing Xcode and re-launching.

```
let performers: [Performer] = try! Performer.fetchAll(in: context)
```

Comment: Where in your code are you casting something?

Comment: I have updated my post @HAS

Comment: @robdashnash "//error here " doesn't help at all. What is the actual error you get?

Comment: And you’re still not casting anything. Is it the `try!` you want to get rid off?

Comment: Kill Xcode and re-launch fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler cannot infer the generic type of `fetchAll<T: NSManagedObject>` because there is no passed parameter with this type. This is the reason why the type must be annotated (not cast).

To return the proper `NSManagedObject` subclass use an `associatedtype` for example

```
protocol Fetchable {
    associatedtype FetchableType: NSManagedObject = Self
    static var entityName : String { get }
    static func fetchAll(withPredicate predicate: NSPredicate? = nil, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [FetchableType]
}

extension Fetchable where FetchableType == Self {

    static var entityName : String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }

    static func fetchAll(withPredicate predicate: NSPredicate? = nil, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [FetchableType] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>(entityName: entityName)
        request.predicate = predicate
        return try context.fetch(request)
  }
}
```

Now this line returns `[Performer]` without a type cast

```
let performers = try! Performer.fetchAll(in: context)
```