# Error casting NSFetchRequest<T> to NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> where T is generic NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, generics, core-data, casting

I want to state that I am fairly new to Swift and I was exploring CoreData concepts. I tried to test with a ToDo list app which on welcome screen shows user created task categories and upon clicking on any category the user will see all the tasks in that group. I tried to create a generic class something like `ToDoListViewController<T: NSManagedObject>` and to implement functionality available for both view controllers(`CategoryViewController`, `TaskViewController`). In that class I created a function `loadItems` which takes a `predicate` as an argument and populates the page with items from a fetch request. So the code roughly looks like this:

```
class ToDoListViewController<T: NSManagedObject>: UITableViewController {

    func loadItems(predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest()
        
        if predicate != nil {
                request.predicate = predicate!
            }
        
        do {
            let items = try context.fetch(request)
            // Do something
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching items from context \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I try to compile I get error:

> Cannot assign value of type `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` to type `NSFetchRequest<T>`

when assigning `request` variable. But if I force cast `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` to `NSFetchRequest<T>` like this:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>
```

everything works fine. Since The [`NSManagedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject) documentation clearly states that it conforms to `NSFetchRequestResult` protocol, why do I have to force cast `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` to `NSFetchRequest<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the type because the generic type of `NSFetchRequest` – which is constrained to `NSFetchRequestResult` – can also be `NSDictionary` or `NSNumber` or `NSManagedObjectID`.

Rather than making a generic type more generic I recommend to use a protocol with associated types like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306874/why-do-i-need-to-cast-this-generic-return-value/48307055#48307055)

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the need of protocol der? whats stopping from using `let request: NSFetchRequest<T> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: String(describing: T.self))` I think the issue OP mentioning here `T.fetchRequest()` is asking for forced type cast but if he decides to switch to use `NSFetchRequest(entityName` even with Generic type it will work :|  BTW +1 to answer in link :)